# T-SQL: Aggregate based on condition

Tags: t-sql

there is a table:

```
start | end | zone
------|-----|-----
  1   |  5  |  3
  3   |  6  |  2
  1   |  3  |  1
  4   |  7  |  4
```

Start and end represent a range. I'd like to get a zone for value of 4, like

```
declare @value as int = 4
select zone from table where @value >= start and @value <= end
```

, and I obtain

```
3
2
4
```

, but I need only one zone from predefined range, for example 2 or 3 and 3 has priority, so if 2 and 3 are present, I'd like to get 3. So, zone 3 is desired result in my example.

How can I solve it?

Comment: How do you determin the priority of the zones?

Comment: how is priority assigned to a zone? In otherwords why would I know that 3 would be the desired output other than you informing me?

Comment: It should be hardcoded like

    if (3 zone is present) return 3
    if (2 zone is present) return 2
    else return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's hard coded you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Value int = 4;

SELECT TOP 1 zone
FROM table
WHERE zone IN (3,2)
AND @Value >= start
AND @Value <= [end] 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN zone = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/FRQOB40548)

### Update

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN zone IN (3,2) THEN zone ELSE NULL END AS zone
FROM @T
WHERE @Value >= start
AND @Value <= [end] 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN zone = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

[Live demo for updated version](http://rextester.com/RCEI36382)

### Update 2

Even though you wrote in your comment that you found a solution thanks to my post, I still want to post a solution here for future readers that might need it:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 zone
    FROM @T
    WHERE zone IN (3,2)
    AND @Value >= start
    AND @Value <= [end] 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN zone = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
)

SELECT zone
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM CTE
)
```

Comment: But it doesn't work for 'else' case (in my comment). I'd like to have a null result for case when there is no a match, for example in case of @Value=0.

Comment: It still doesn't work for case @Value=0, when value is outside of the declared ranges.

Comment: You want to get null even if there is no record where the value falls within the range?

Comment: Yes. [text to commit the comment]

Comment: Currently not near a computer, will edit again later.

Comment: So, thanks, I was inspired by your solution and I solved my issue.